# How can i change Bootstrap 1170px width to 990px as designed in Photoshop?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, width

I have downloaded Bootstrap 3.0 which have default width of 1170px.
my layout has been designed under 990px width.

how can i make it work under 990px?

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question (I'm rather new with Bootstrap) but isn't the whole idea of Bootstrap to design and work completely independent of viewport size? (i.e. the opposite of designing something for a specific width or screen resolution)

Answer (score 1):

You can customise it by default - http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Answer (score 0):

If you use bootstrap with no responsive design you can simply override .container class in your styles.css like

```
.container {
  width: 990px;
}
```

but if you want your site to be responsive with max-width centered block equal to 990px, you can do this in your css file

```
.container {
  max-width: 990px;
}
```